# Object Detection using recolored image and without Bounding Box

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, colors, object-detection

I have multiple images where I wish to detect one particular feature from the image. Instead of drawing a bounding box around the image, I have recolored the object to detect a different color since it is important that I get the shape of the object. How could I go about creating a model that uses the image with the recolored object to find the object in a new picture and recolor the object in that picture as well?

My case:
I want to recognize one lego in a black and white image, so I recolor the lego in the image green. Thus, I have 2 images that are the exact same except for the fact that in one, the object being detected is another color. I want the model to take in a random black and white image with a lego and recolor the lego.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.